# Prevent TabbedPanel from redrawing during animation

Tags: python, kivy

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Here's an example code to show the problem, 
when the ('Press me') button is pressed and the widget resized(white box come within view), the TabbedPanel redraws like a glitch (even though its not).

I've tried changing the layout order and toyed a bit with the animation, no

I wish to prevent that blinking behaviour of the tabbedpanel on the left.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            id: main_screen
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            TabbedPanel:
                do_default_tab: False
                tab_pos: 'left_top'
                tab_width: main_screen.height/4
                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: 'four'
                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: 'three'
                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: 'two'
                TabbedPanelItem:
                    text: 'one'
            BoxLayout:
                id: swidget
                slide: 0  
                size_hint: None, None
                height: main_screen.height
                width: self.slide
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1,1,1,1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size 
        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '33dp'
            text: 'Press me'
            on_release: root.display_widget(swidget)
''')

class Main(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def display_widget(self, widget):
        swidget = widget

        if swidget.slide == 0:
            anim = Animation(slide=105, duration=0.6)
            anim.start(widget)
        else:
            anim = Animation(slide=0, duration=0.6)
            anim.start(widget)


class TabbedApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


TabbedApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`AnchorLayout`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.anchorlayout.html) to be the parent of `swidget` / `BoxLayout` and when the animation starts, it won't impact the instantiated `TabbedPanel`.

## Snippets

```
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'right'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 0

            BoxLayout:
                id: swidget
                slide: 0  
                size_hint_x: None
                width: self.slide
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1,1,1,1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
```

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)